# Applying the implicit function theorem on $e^y+x^2ye^{-x}=3$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, implicit-function-theorem

I know the implicit function theorem but no clue how to show this..

> Show that $e^y+x^2ye^{-x}=3$ implicitly defines a unique function $y=f(x)$ defined on all real numbers.

Comment: Can you state the version of the implicit function theorem you're familiar with? That will help people fit an answer to your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: note that $x^2 e^{-x} \ge 0$, and so for each $x$, the function $y \mapsto e^y + x^2e^{-x}y$ is strictly increasing.

Comment: F(x,y) Strictly increasing means that $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}\exists!y\in\mathbb{R}$ such that  $F(x,y)=0$ $\implies$  $y=f(x)$ is unique and defined on all real numbers right?

Comment: @Archimedess Unfortunately not (e.g. $\arctan$ is strictly increasing and has a range only of $(-\pi/2, \pi/2)$), but it does mean the function is injective, which means if there exists a $y$, then there exists a unique $y$. To get existence, try using the intermediate value theorem, and the fact that the function tends to $\pm \infty$ as $x \to \pm \infty$ respectively.

Comment: Thanks Theo, i got it now.